# How can I smooth the rate of change of a number data?

Tags: c++

I'm a collage student and I'm new here. I've been having a problem with my assignment which I have to calculate the speed of a car. I've done with the right algorithm (using a 1/60s timer) and formula except that I have a problem with displaying the speed number. The output data changes very fast in 1 seconds (Yes, it will change very frequently in 1s since I use a 1/60s timer). Is there any way to smooth the rate of change within that output?

I've tried to round the number but the rate of change still very quick.

```
    //For example Car1 object is moving along the x axis
//My method to calculate the speed with a 1/60s timer
//every 1/60s timeout:

    if(distanceToggler == true ){        
        vDistance[0] = car->getCarPos().x();
    }
    else {
        vDistance[1] = car->getCarPos().x();
    }
          //if Ture assign to vDistance[0] else assign to vDistance[1]

    distanceToggler = !distanceToggler;

    if ( (vDistance[1] - vDistance[0]) >= 0 ){
    defaultSetting.editCurrentCarSpeed( (vDistance[1]-vDistance[0]) / (0.6f) );
    }
    currentCarSpeed = (vDistance[0]-vDistance[1]) / (0.6f);
```

Comment: What do you actually expect? One suspicious part of the code is that you toggle the indexes but don't take that into consideration when you calculate the speed. One more suspicious thing is that you don't let your speed to be negative (which is a valid value for speed).

Comment: Do you want to limit the change of actual value, or just limit the displayed value's rate of change (IOW display different value that the actual value, if that changes too fast)?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to smooth noisy values arriving frequently is to keep a kind of running average and only adjust it by a percentage of each new value:

```
const float smooth_factor = 0.05f;

// Assume the first sample is correct (alternatively you could initialize to 0)
float smooth_v;
std::cin >> smooth_v;

// Read samples and output filtered samples
for(float v; std::cin >> v; )
{
    smooth_v = (1.0f - smooth_factor) * smooth_v + smooth_factor * v;
    std::cout << smooth_v << std::endl;
}
```

The smaller you make `smooth_factor`, the slower the "smooth" value will change in response to new data.  You can tweak this value to something suitable to your application.

This is a fast alternative to taking an unweighted windowed average (although such averages can be computed in constant time), although it's slightly different in that every historical value has some effect (which reduces with time).